# RenderBody() is Leading to an exception( cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderBody" method.)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to render an view page inside the  add customer view page ,this is giving me an error in the view page , which is not able to load in the html view,
Thanks in advance..

Create New user

```
                            @model acer.Table1

                           @{
                            ViewBag.Title = "CreateNewUser";

                         }

                        <h2>CreateNewUser</h2>


                       @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
                        {
                           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                      @Html.Partial("View")
                      <h4></h4>
                        <hr />


                    Shared view code is below-->
                    @{
                         Layout = "~/Views/Shared/View.cshtml";
                       }

                     <!DOCTYPE html>

                    <html>
                      <head>

                           <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
                 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
                    [enter image description here][1]scale=1">

            </head>

            <body>
                <div class="sidenav">
                    <a href="Home">Home</a>
                    <a href="Profile">Profile</a>
                    <a href="Employees">Employees</a>
                    <a href="CreateNewUser">CreateNewUser</a>
                </div>
                <div class="main">

                </div>


                             <div class="container body-content">
                               @RenderBody()

                                 @*<footer>
                                  <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - MyASP.NET 
                                        Application</p>
                                    </footer>*@
                           </div>

                          @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
                         @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
                        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
                       </body>
                       </html>
```

// the error message Picture Shows in the below link...
[image]
      [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyuFE.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyuFE.png

Comment: `@RenderBody()` goes in the Layout file, not the view file. And you do not put `<html>` and `<head>` tags in the view - they go in the layout (along with common code)

Comment: Remove `@RenderBody()` from view file and keep it in Layout file

Answer (score 0):

Dont call this  `@Html.Partial("View")` directly.
Create new partial view called "_InnerView" inside this view use
`@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/View.cshtml";
  }`

and then called @Html.Partial("_InnerView")

Hope this will help you.